# Access model's field in html attributes in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

Anyway, I am using MVC Razor, and I want to implement a text area, where user can input text with HTML-formatting and some field (or textblock) where this text will instantly appear in formatted way while user is typing it.

Right now I have a test label where I want to display the inputted text and the text area, where user will type. The model has two fields: `ID` and `Text`.

```
<label id="test">There will appear typed text</label>
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => template.Text, new { @class = "span10", rows = 12, @onkeyup = "$('#test').text('testing');" })
```

Right now the listener on `TextArea` works fine and puts "testing" inside the label. However I want it to put dynamic value, and also I need the test label to have dynamic id, like "test_1" (since there will be more than 1 pair textare-label). I tried something like this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => template.Text, new { @class = "span10", rows = 12, @onkeyup = "$('#test_@template.Id').text('@template.Text');" })
```

But this didn't work. So, I have two questions:

1. How to pass model's fields `ID` and `Text` inside of the html attributes in @onkeyup
2. What container should I better use instead of `label` to correctly display the html code.

Answer (score 2):

1) It's just string concatenation

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => template.Text,
    new { @class = "span10", rows = 12,
    @onkeyup = "$('#test_" + @template.Id + "').text('" + @template.Text + "');" })
```

2) Label seems ok here if it describes the text area field

**Edit**

Since you've got jquery let's drop the `@onkeyup` and do this unobtrusively

```
<div id="format"></div>
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => template.Text,
    new { @class="span10", rows=12, id="code" })

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#code").on("keyup", function(e) {
            var markup = $(this).val();
            var markupDiv = $("<div></div>").html(markup);
            $("#format").empty().append(markupDiv.html());
        });
    });
</script>
```

We use an in-memory div `$("<div></div>")` to encode the markup then append it to the div placeholder.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BD2Q7/)

Comment: Thank you, but now I got two new problems:
1. Label doesn't support multiline text
2. By using @template.Text I get only the saved value from model, instead of the latest text, entered by user.

Comment: Also label doesn't display html formatting. I tried using `@Html.Raw` on a `@template.Text` - but it didn't helped.

Comment: Nevermind, found a solution. Will add it to the post :)

Comment: Thanks for the jquery example, but I guess I found a solution that works fine. Look at the update of the post.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer rather than an update to your question

Answer (score 0):

UPD. Solution found! Special thanks to Jason for help.

```
<div id="test-@template.Id">@Html.Raw(@template.Text)</div>
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => template.Text, new { @class = "span10", rows = 12, id = "textarea-" + @template.Id, @onkeyup = "$('#test-" + @template.Id + "').html(document.getElementById('textarea-" + @template.Id + "').value);" })
```